# DataTable filter function not working: Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, datatable

I am using Razor syntax for displaying a view. I am looking to filter the datatable that I have infront of me. However, even with the presence of normal script, the filter should work, but it doesn't. I am not sure what could be the reason.

Here is my code:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $('.table').DataTable(); // this provides a DataTable plugin feature that has search functionality, but for some reason it is not working
        //$('.hasTooltip').tooltip();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.20/datatables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.20/datatables.min.css" />

<table class="table table-hover" id="tblgrpDetail">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Name
      </th>

      <th>
        Address
      </th>
      <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="myTable">
    @foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>

      <td class="Name">
        <span>@item.Name</span> @Html.DropDownList("Name", (SelectList)ViewBag.objName, new { id = "Name", @class = "form-control JGID", style = "display:none; width:200px;" })
      </td>

      <td class="Address">
        <span>@item.Address</span> @Html.DropDownList("Address", (SelectList)ViewBag.objAddr, new { id = "Address", @class = "form-control Address", style = "display:none; width:200px;" })
      </td>
      <td>
        <a class="Edit btn btn-success hasTooltip" href="javascript:;" data-placement="bottom" title="Edit"><span><img src="~/Icons/icons8-edit-20.png" /></span></a>
        <a class="Delete btn btn-danger hasTooltip" href="javascript:;" data-placement="bottom" title="Delete"><span><img src="~/Icons/icons8-delete-trash-20.png" /></span> </a>
        <a class="Update btn btn-info hasTooltip" href="javascript:;" style="display:none" data-placement="bottom" title="Update"><span><img src="~/Icons/icons8-update-20.png" /></span> </a>
        <a class="Cancel btn btn-danger hasTooltip" href="javascript:;" style="display:none" data-placement="bottom" title="Cancel"><span><img src="~/Icons/icons8-cancel-20.png" /></span></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    }
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The inbuilt datatable search functionality itself is not working. I tried searching the web and SO for the same, but failed to land on any correct answer.

If you can tell me the right direction, it would be great help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: pls add "bFilter": true in datatable declaration

Comment: @Mustufa let me check. Thanks :)

Comment: @Mustufa nope. It is not working.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37751528/jquery-datatable-filter-search-not-working

Comment: This snippet seems working to me.

Comment: I just now found that if I write select dropdown instead of @Html.DropDownlist Helper it gets successfully filtered, but not with this case.

Comment: Show us the final compiled html

Comment: Can you please share your generated HTML  so we can easily understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found very strange behavior of DropdownListFor method, not sure whether it is a bug or  genuineness. When I replace this with  markup, it perfectly works, but not otherwise. I used select markup instead of DropDownList and it worked!